# How to give a shadow to a Custom Path arc in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

As the question says ...... I need to add a shadow to an arc drawn by custom paint. I tried our the drawShadow() method like this :

```
Path a = Path()..arcTo(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: pieRadius), -(pi / 2) + val1 + val3 + val4 ,val2, false);
canvas.drawCircle(center,pieRadius/* * 0.4*/, outerArc);
canvas.drawPath(a, innerArc1);
    canvas.drawShadow(a, Colors.black, 3, true);
```

But this results in a shadow like this :

[image]

But I want a shadow equally surrounding the arc just like the boxShadow property of Container.

[image]

In this manner (The area between blue marking and arc should be under shadow).

Thankyou in advance for help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. After some experimentation, the best solution I found was to draw two arcs, one for the arc itself and another underneath for the shadow. The shadow arc has a small offset, and can have its own paint, with a `MaskFilter.blur`.

```dart
Paint arcPaint = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.red,
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeWidth = 15;

Paint shadowPaint = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.grey[600]
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeWidth = 15
  ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, 5);

Path path = Path();
path.addArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: pieRadius), -(pi / 2) + val1 + val3 + val4, val2);

canvas.drawPath(path.shift(Offset(2, 2)), shadowPaint);
canvas.drawPath(path, arcPaint);
```